# Lubuntu - how inhibit ALL trackpad actions unless Ctrl key is simultaneously pressed

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad

On Lubuntu, how can I set the touchpad so that it only functions if the Ctrl key is simultaneously pressed?

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. The green check mark next to your answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an exact answer, but close enough to serve. The following addition to my .bashrc toggles the touchpad.

```
tp(){ # toggle touchpad, tp n (1=off, 0=on)
  synclient TouchpadOff=${1:-1}
}
```